# Unix diff to only print relevant diff

Tags: unix, diff

I have these two files

File: `11`

```
11
456123
```

File: `22`

```
11
789
```

Output of `diff 11 22`

```
2c2
< 456123
---
> 789
```

Output to be

```
< 456123
> 789
```

I want it to not print the `2c2` and `---` lines. I looked at the man page but could not locate any help. Any ideas? The file has more than 1000 lines.

Comment: Fixed the diff. If you're going to provide test cases, at least provide ones that work :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about `diff 11 22 | grep "^[<|>]"`?

**Update**: As knitti pointed out the correct pattern is `^[<>]`

Comment: +1. Seems the simplest solution and UNIX was _built_ on the shoulders of pipelines :-)

Comment: grep "^[<>]" # character classes do not need to pipe to split the different possibilities

Comment: It's not obsolete, it's wrong, because that greps lines that start with a pipe too.

Comment: @wilhelmtell, then we must include \ and / too, i think they are also used somehow (e.g. no newline at end of file)

Comment: This may produce strange results when dealing with html, because of its <>.

Answer (score 2):

Diff has a whole host of useful options like `--old-group-format` that are described very briefly in help.  They are expanded in http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/diff/Line_Group_Formats.html

The following is producing something similar to what you want.

```
    diff 11.txt 22.txt --unchanged-group-format=""  --changed-group-format="<%<>%>"

    <456123
    >789
```

You might also need to play with `--old-group-format=format` (groups hunks containing only lines from the first file) `--new-group-format=format` `--old-line-format=format` (formats lines just from the first file) and `--new-line-format=format` etc

Disclaimer - I have not used this for real before, in fact I have only just understood them. If you have further questions I am happy to look at it later.

**Edited** to change order of lines